# string dynamic allocation in C

Tags: c, string, dynamic, malloc, allocation

I'm writing a function that needs to:

1. Get a full sentence from the user
2. Dynamically assign for each word a memory block that can contain it
3. Copy it to it and save the address to the * words pointer array

I wrote a loop that in each iteration gets a word from the sentence the user inserted, but I can't Dynamically allocate it properly.
This is what I have:

```
char str[50];
while(scanf("%s", str) != EOF)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *words = (char*) malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
}
```

I also  need to make sure that:

- If the function succeeds, it returns the number of words entered.
- If memory allocation fails the function returns -1.

Comment: Each loop overwrites the previous value of `words`, which anyway goes out of scope at the end of the loop. You need an array of pointers, before the loop, and an index variable to access the array (and count the elements for later). You don't have that array mentioned in the question (3).

Comment: "Get a full sentence from the user" - You are reading words from the user in an infinite loop (it is infinite unless the user enters EOF into stdin, which requires a special key combination on most platforms). Don't you want to read until the end of sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `while(scanf("%s", str) != EOF)` is a potencial infinite loop, this will only stop if you feed the program with `EOF` signal through the command line.

For a single string that hodls all the words you are going to need to reallocate memory at every read to increase the memory space where the string is saved.

You can do something like this:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HyT0nnqa8)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ret_words(char **words) { //double pointer argument
    char str[50];
    char *temp = malloc(1); //first allocation required
    int count = 0;

    if(temp == NULL){       //allocation error
        return -1;
    }
    do{
        temp = realloc(temp, strlen(str) + strlen(temp) + 2); //reallocate space on
                                                              //each iteration
        if(temp == NULL){                                      
            return -1;
        }
        count++; //count words
    } while (scanf("%49s", str) == 1 && strcat(temp, str) //scan str and append to temp
      && getchar() != '\n' && strcat(temp, " "));         //with spaces between

    *words = temp; //assign temp to words
    return count; //return word count
}
```

```
int main() {

    int ret;
    char *words; //pointer to the array of strings
    puts("Enter the string");
    putchar('>');
    ret = ret_words(&words); //returned number of words on success, -1 on error

    printf("Inputed string: %s\nNumber of words: %d", words, ret); //test print
}
```

**Constraints: There cannot be any spaces after the last inputed word for the cycle to conclude.**

Now, if you want bi-dimensional array like structure, dynamically allocated not only for the words themselves, but also for the pointers that point to those strings you will need something a bit more special, a triple pointer.

Think of it as a pointer to an array of strings, this is what you need as an argument of your function in order to make the changes permanent in the caller function, in this case, the main function.

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/S10bkpqpI)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ret_words(char ***words) { //triple pointer argument
    char str[50];
    int count = 0;
    char **temp = malloc(sizeof *temp); //allocate a pointer to pointer to char

    if(temp == NULL){       //allocation error
        return -1;
    }
    do {
        temp = realloc(temp, (count + 1) * sizeof *temp); //reallocate space at every scan
        if(temp == NULL){
            return -1;
        } 
        temp[count] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        count++;
    } while (scanf("%49s",temp[count - 1]) == 1 //scan str and append to temp
      && getchar() != '\n');                    //with spaces between

    *words = temp; //assing the allocated array of pointer to the argument
    return count; //return word count
}
```

```
int main()
{ 
    char **words; // pointer to pointer to navigate the array of strings

    int ret;
    puts("Enter the string");
    putchar('>');
    ret = ret_words(&words); //returned number of words on success, -1 on error

    for(int i = 0; i < ret; i++) //print each stored one word string
        printf("Word %d: %s\n",i + 1, words[i]);

    printf("Word count: %d", ret); //print the number of words
}
```

**Constraints: There cannot be any spaces after the last inputed word for the cycle to conclude.**

Note that there is an extra level of indirection due to the fact that these assignments are made through the arguments of the function, if they were to be used in place or returned by the function you would only need a simple pointer, in the first sample, and a double pointer in the second sample.

Comment: The question states "(2) Dynamically assign for **each** word a memory block that can contain it". However, in your answer, you are assigning one big memory block for **all** words. Although the question does not explicitly state that every word should have its own "malloc memory block", it would seem more obvious to give every word its own such block. This would also have the advantage that `realloc` would not have to copy the entire memory buffer several times. However, I am still upvoting your answer, because the one memory block can be considered as containing sub-blocks for every word.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, that didn't occur to me, it does seem like a more correct interpretation. I guess I'll have to add a solution for it. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following restrictions already embedded in your code fragment:

- the maximum word length is 49 bytes,
- the user signals the end of file after the end of the sentence.

Here is a simple function that constructs an array of pointers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct context {
    char **array;
    int count;
};

int read_sentence(struct context *cp) {
    char buf[50];

    cp->array = NULL;
    cp->count = 0;

    while (scanf("%49s", buf) == 1) {
        // another word was read
        char **new_array = realloc(cp->array, (cp->count + 1) * sizeof(*new_array));
        char *p = strdup(buf);
        if (new_array == NULL || p == NULL) {
            // allocation error: free previously allocated memory and return -1
            free(p);
            if (new_array != NULL) {
                cp->array = new_array;
            }
            while (cp->count > 0) {
                free(cp->array[--cp->count]);
            }
            free(cp->array);
            cp->array = NULL;
            return -1;
        }
        cp->array = new_array;
        cp->array[cp->count++] = p;
    }
    return cp->count;
}
```